# Is it ok to wrap a singleton?

Tags: c#, redis

I'm using SignalR with StackExchange Redis. What I gather from the 
[basic usage doc](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Basics.md) is the way to implement this is using a singleton. I've never used this patter before. My class looks like this:

```
public class RedisInstance
{
    public static readonly RedisInstance Instance = new RedisInstance();
    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Redis;

    public RedisInstance()
    {
        Redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
    }
}
```

I've been using it like this

```
public class DashHub : Hub
{
    public void MapUser(int userId)
    {
        var user = new AppUser() {Id = userId, ConnectionIds = new List<string>() {Context.ConnectionId } };
        var db = RedisInstance.Redis.GetDatabase();

        var userJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

        db.StringSet(userId.ToString(), userJson);
    }
```

But I was thinking this is rather constricting if I build this out and down the line want to use something other than Redis, so I was going to do this

```
public class DatabaseRepository
{
    IDatabase db;

    public DatabaseRepository()
    {
        this.db = RedisInstance.Redis.GetDatabase();
    }

    public void Insert(string key, string value)
    {
        db.StringSet(key, value);
    }
}
```

and then reference this in my other classes. Am I using these patterns appropriately here? Are there any issues with using a singleton in this way? This may seem straightforward but I'm just learning this and want to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

I've not had much experience using redis so this code may not be 100% correct. But it would be better if you used dependency injection to manage your singleton. That way you aren't having to code your class to be a singleton and if you want/need to change it at any point it will be very simple. eg

**DI layer**

```
builder.RegisterType<RedisInstance>().As<IRedisInstance>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<DatabaseRepository>().As<IDatabaseRepository>();
```

**Redis Instance**

```
public class RedisInstance : IRedisInstance
{
    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Redis;

    public RedisInstance()
    {
        Redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
    }
}
```

**DatabaseRepository**

```
public class DatabaseRepository: IDatabaseRepository
{
   private readonly IRedisInstance db;

   public DatabaseRepository(IRedisInstance redisInstance)
   {
      this.db = redisInstance;
   }

   public void Insert(string key, string value)
   {
     this.db.Redis.StringSet(key, value);
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public class DashHub : Hub
{
  private readonly IDatabaseRepository repo;

  public DashHub(IDatabaseRepository repo)
  {
   this.repo = repo;
   }
    public void MapUser(int userId)
    {
        var db = this.repo.Insert("blah", "blah");
    }
}
```

**Additional**

I'm not sure why you would want your data access to be in singleton mode as you would want your connection to close and having a singleton will mean that multiple requests will be accessing the same instance. So you can now change your dependency injection to be like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<RedisInstance>().As<IRedisInstance>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: well, that's part of my question. reading the redis docs, i was asking if what they are saying means i should be using a singleton or not.

Answer (score 1):

When your code has a singleton, I would assume that anyone can use that singleton. Otherwise, it is not a singleton (a class that has by coincidence only one instance is not a singleton. A class that by design can only have one instance is a singleton).

No you say you "wrap a singleton". The wrapper would again be a singleton. (You can of course have a class with many instances that each hold a reference to the same singleton, but that wouldn't be a wrapper).

So you have a singleton, and a wrapper singleton which behind the scenes refers to the same singleton. I would be worried that being able to use the same singleton in two different ways would cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (pseudo code):

```
public Interface IKeyValueRepository
{
    void Insert(string key, string value);
     //Put other methods here
}

//Redis Implementation
public RedisRepository : IKeyValueRepository
{
    private static ConnectionMultiplexer _redis;

    public RedisRepository ()
    {
         _redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
    }

    public void Insert(string key, string value)
    {
        var db = _redis.GetDatabase();       
        db.StringSet(key, value);
    }
    //And so forth
}
```

Then you should be able to swap thing out pretty easily and mock the repository as well.

Comment: so using a singleton isn't correct in this case? When they say "store and re-use this(ConnectionMultiplexer)" they mean just make it a static field in a class?

Comment: It depends on how you want to use the connection.  If you want to maintain it across instances, use static , if you want multiple connection instances for each new repository, then it would just be private and not static.